# ValueError: matrix must be 2-dimensional when passing two arrays to the function

Tags: python, numpy

I have a function which is written entirely in numpy functions and takes two input values. The function consists of some matrix operations and when I pass two large arrays It gives me an ValueError: matrix must be 2-dimensional. Using loops and numpy.apply_along_axis will fix the problem but these methods with make the code very slow.

The following is the code I have written

```py
import numpy as np
import random
data = np.random.normal(size=600*600*2)
data = data.reshape(600*600,2)

def fun(x,y):
    f1 = sin(x)*cos(y)
    f2 = cos(x)*sin(y)
    eig1 = f1*np.mat([[f1],[f2]])
    eig2 = f2*np.mat([[f2+f1],[f1]])
    return np.sum(np.linalg.eig(eig1*eig2.T)[0])


fun(data[:,0],data[:,1])
```

It gives me the following error

ValueError: matrix must be 2-dimensional

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue using [XGBoost](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and managed to solve it as follows:

Instead of:

```
import numpy as np
x_trainNPArray = np.array(x_train)
x_testNPArray = np.array(x_test)
y_trainNPArray = np.array(y_train)
y_testNPArray = np.array(y_test)
model.fit(x_trainNPArray,y_trainNPArray)
...
```

, I used:

```
x_trainNPArray = np.vstack(x_trainNPArray)
x_testNPArray = np.vstack(x_testNPArray)
y_trainNPArray = np.vstack(y_trainNPArray)
y_testNPArray = np.vstack(y_testNPArray )
model.fit(x_trainNPArray,y_trainNPArray)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

And the traceback is:

```
     ...: fun(data[:,0],data[:,1])                                                                     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-262-144f145bebe5> in <module>
     10 
     11 
---> 12 fun(data[:,0],data[:,1])

<ipython-input-262-144f145bebe5> in fun(x, y)
      5     f1 = np.sin(x)*np.cos(y)
      6     f2 = np.cos(x)*np.sin(y)
----> 7     eig1 = f1*np.mat([[f1],[f2]])
      8     eig2 = f2*np.mat([[f2+f1],[f1]])
      9     return np.sum(np.linalg.eig(eig1*eig2.T)[0])

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/matrixlib/defmatrix.py in asmatrix(data, dtype)
     69 
     70     """
---> 71     return matrix(data, dtype=dtype, copy=False)
     72 
     73 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/matrixlib/defmatrix.py in __new__(subtype, data, dtype, copy)
    149         shape = arr.shape
    150         if (ndim > 2):
--> 151             raise ValueError("matrix must be 2-dimensional")
    152         elif ndim == 0:
    153             shape = (1, 1)

ValueError: matrix must be 2-dimensional
```

So the problem is the input to the `np.mat` function.  What's that?

```
In [263]: data.shape                                                                                   
Out[263]: (360000, 2)
```

The sin/cos calls don't change shape, so:

```
In [264]: [[data[:,0]],[data[:,1]]]                                                                                             
Out[264]: 
[[array([-0.95915424,  1.38013956,  1.26480082, ...,  1.34129623,
          1.14664781,  0.90385798])],
 [array([-0.77785621,  0.695089  ,  1.17894725, ..., -0.2891861 ,
          0.47051436, -0.22550854])]]
In [265]: np.array([[data[:,0]],[data[:,1]]])                                                          
Out[265]: 
array([[[-0.95915424,  1.38013956,  1.26480082, ...,  1.34129623,
          1.14664781,  0.90385798]],

       [[-0.77785621,  0.695089  ,  1.17894725, ..., -0.2891861 ,
          0.47051436, -0.22550854]]])
In [266]: _.shape                                                                                      
Out[266]: (2, 1, 360000)
```

So you are trying to give `np.mat` a 3d array.

`np.mat` works if I drop the []:

```
In [274]: np.mat([data[:,0],data[:,1]]).shape                                                          
Out[274]: (2, 360000)
```

but `f1*np.mat([f1,f2])` has a problem with the matrix product:

```
In [275]: data[:,0]*np.mat([data[:,0],data[:,1]])                                                      
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-275-555ec143af3f> in <module>
----> 1 data[:,0]*np.mat([data[:,0],data[:,1]])

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/matrixlib/defmatrix.py in __rmul__(self, other)
    224 
    225     def __rmul__(self, other):
--> 226         return N.dot(other, self)
    227 
    228     def __imul__(self, other):

ValueError: shapes (360000,) and (2,360000) not aligned: 360000 (dim 0) != 2 (dim 0)
```

By making a `np.mat` the `*` is now a `dot` product, not a element-wise product.

Comment: I am creating a matrix with np.mat. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mat.html. I am creating a column matrix with np.mat

Comment: But the `[[f1],[f2]]` input adds an extra dimension.  By the way, we are dicsouraging the use of `np.mat` now.  It's rarely needed.

Comment: Can you please suggest a way to fix this?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  Even if I drop the  `[]`, so `np.mat` works, I still get an error: `eig1 = f1*np.mat([f1,f2])`, it's trying to do a np.dot with a (n,) and (2,n) array (matrix).

Comment: I am defining a function which takes generates a 2x2 matrix and then return the sum of eigenvalues of this 2x2 matrix. Now I have a data which is similar to the random data generated. What I am trying to to do is to evaluate the function for the each row in the generated data in faster way.  If I run a loop over data, I can fix this but it is very slow. I also tried using numpy.apply_along_axis but this is slower than the loop

Comment: You need to track dimensions carefully when develop code like this.  Test and test again,  Don't assume.