# Xgboost-ValueError: Please reshape the input data X into 2-dimensional matrix in python

Tags: python, xgboost

I use XGBoost Algortihm for text mining but in below code I keep getting an error.

```
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
from numpy import *
xgb=XGBClassifier()
xgb.fit(df['doc_vector'],df.cat1)
```

How can I fix this? Thank you.
[image]

Below types and print of the objects

[image]

Comment: Please do not use images for showing your code or errors: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 4):

Actually I got the solution from [ValueError: matrix must be 2-dimensional when passing two arrays to the function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56470894/valueerror-matrix-must-be-2-dimensional-when-passing-two-arrays-to-the-function)
Thanks.

```
xgb=XGBClassifier()
xgb.fit(np.vstack(df['doc_vector']),df.cat1)
predictions = xgb.predict(np.vstack(val['doc_vector']))
```

Comment: Please consider upvoting the answer that helped you from the link you posted.